# Unable to inject Datasource in Managed Bean

Tags: java, jsf, dependency-injection, jsf-2

Hi i am trying to load list of Students onload of a Page in JSF using h:datatable tag

```
<h:dataTable value="#{studentBean2.studentList}" var="student">
  ......
  .....
</h:datatable>
```

now my ManagedBean is as follows

```
public class StudentBeanTwo {
     public StudentBeanTwo() {
         init();
     }

@Resource(name="jdbc/rahul_sample_pool",type=DataSource.class)
private  DataSource dataSource; 

private void init(){
    .......
    ....... 
    if(this.getStudentList() == null){
       loadStudents();              
    }   
}

private void loadStudents() throws Exception{
    Connection con = null;
    .....
    .....
    try{

       if(this.dataSource == null){
          System.out.println(" DataSource() is null  ");
       }
       con = this.dataSource.getConnection();
       ........
    }
}
```

now my Question is why my datasource is null,

i check by annotating @Resource to a variable in another servlet an i am
able to create the connection,

so whats the problem in the above managed-bean,

why datasource is null ?
The container is not able to inject Resource, why ?

please help me out

Comment: You did not show the full code, could it be that you are mixing JSF and CDI-annotations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Björns comment: Injection is done *after* construction and you call your init method from the constructor.

You could annotate your `init()` method with `@PostConstruct`. Then it will be called after construction and not during construction.

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
...
    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        ...
        if(this.getStudentList() == null){
           loadStudents();              
        }   
    }
```

Then the init method gets called every time the bean is constructed (depending on your bean's scope).